# Popmenu is not aligned on center of listview row

Tags: android, listview, popupmenu

Below is the code I am using to display popupmenu , so that it appears on the center of the row of my listview

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                final int pos, long id) {
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, arg1);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                popup = new PopupMenu(context, arg1,Gravity.CENTER );
            }
            //Inflating the Popup using xml file  
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.listmenu, popup.getMenu());  
            ///some code
            return true;
        }
    });
```

But the problem is popmenu always appears on the left side.
When I give Gravity.RIGHT, popmenu does appear on right most side of row.
What is going wrong with the center display??

Answer (score 0):

you can give anchor

```
showPopup(viewOfWherePopupmenuShows,popmenuNameList.size());


PopupMenu popMenu = new PopupMenu(Activity.this,v)
int size =popmenuNameList.size();
for(int i =0; i <size; i++){
 popMenu.getMenu().add(popmenuNameList.get(i)).setIcon(R.drawable.logo);

}
 popMenu.show();
```

...

```
protected void showPopupMenu(View v, int size){
   //create instance
   PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(Activity.this,v);
   //inflating the popup using xml
   popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_popup_list),popup.getMenu());

for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
 popmenu.getMenu().add(0,i+99,0,"text").setcheckable(true).setChecked(false);
}
}
```